# How to solve Url encode and decode issue with some special character and numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net, encoding, decode, request.querystring

I have a some url data save in database that data is saved in as a encryption format like this below:

```
i.e: Wwrjf5OxVEznsWInNFwucg==
```

that was okay but sum time encryption will be like this

```
i.e: Wwrjf5OxV+EznsWInNFwucg==
```

in that case when i read the 
Request.QueryString["QueryString"] or Request.Params["Params"]

then i will get the string with the space between encryption if there is a value with "+" between the encryption so how can i solve this issue of "+" in QueryString or Params read.

please let me know a batter solution for solve this issue

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this for url encode and decode.

```
string encodedUrl = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["QueryString"]);
string decodedUrl = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(encodedUrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

You've sort of already answered this question in your title... You need to URL-encode it before it goes into your QueryString and decode it when it comes back out.

Write:

```
Request.QueryString["QueryString"] = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(myEncryptedString);
```

Read:

```
var encryptedResult = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["QueryString"]);
```